# Data structure question

Tags: c++, data-structures

> You are going to write a computer program where the requirement of the data collection is that it should be kept in order and there will be a great deal of adding and deleting from the collection. What data structure would be best to model this?

I was thinking vector, but that's not ordered. Any suggestions? I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face but looking through my notes I can't find anything that clicks.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming this is homework?

Comment: If this is a homework, please add a homework tag.

Comment: As the question stands, it has nothing to do with C++. Do you want to know what data-structure to use in C++, or do you want to know what data-structure to use in general?

Comment: please add a homework tag, and have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/)

Comment: Define what you mean by "order" (insertion, or some other), there are lots of container types (vector/deque/set/map/list) etc. They all have different characteristics, I would urge you to look at each and the characteristics and make a decision that way - only you know your requirements.

Comment: What data structures have you studied so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic answer to that is: a Tree. Simplest would be a binary search tree but you also might want to look for Red-Black trees or AVL trees. The [boost graph library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/index.html) might also be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

See...if the adding and deleting is only from the front and end you can prefer using [QUEUE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29)
but if it can be from anywhere in the data then i would suggest [link list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)....though a bit difficult to manage but efficient deletion and updation can happen....
Hope this helps....
EDIT....
to add to my answer and being more precise...[tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) is an option.....

Answer (score 0):

I think vector is enough for the spec.

```
std::vector<int> d;
d.push_back(1);
d.push_back(4);
d.push_back(2);
d.push_back(3);
std::vector<int>::const_iterator it;
for (it = d.begin(); it != d.end(); it++) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl; // show 1 4 2 3
}
// language: cpp
```

Or do you mean "ORDER" is "SORTED"?